# Add lines with geom_seg to stacked barplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add lines to the stacked barplot I created.

I have been trying to do so with geom_segment, first creating a data.frame and then adding the start and end points of each segment.Not having much success though.

Here is my code without attempts to add lines:

```
ggplot(d3, aes(x = factor(interact), y = percent, fill = factor(mrs_d90d_c))) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.7) +
    coord_flip() +
    scale_y_continuous() +
    labs(x = "VSS Dichotomized 0=control, 1=intervention", y = "percent", 
    fill = "MRS at 90 days")
```

More specifically, I am trying to draw lines between different elements of the bottom two and top two barplots seperately. This is the desired result: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AONdy.png

Link to sample data: https://pastebin.com/7yeWN5Qy

Comment: It's preferable to include the data in the question as outside links may die in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create those lines manually, you can use the geom_segment() function, which is part of the tidyverse package.

Download the tidyverse package:

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
```

Load it in:

```
load(tidyverse)
```

Manually insert the desired segments (lines) into your plot to connect different elements of the stacked bars.

Enter the following to get help on how to use geom_segment():

```
?geom_segment
```

Here's a simple example of how to use it. Say you want a basic segment from coordinates (3,4) to (5,6):

```
geom_segment(aes(x = 3, y = 4, xend = 5, yend = 6), size = 1)
```